# Nokogiri to_xhtml puts doctype before <?xml

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to use Nokogiri to parse and update some xhtml files (fixing image sizes).

The parsing and updating works well but when I save the document with:

```
doc.to_xhtml(:indent_text => "\t", :indent=>1, :encoding => 'UTF-8')
```

The first two lines change from (original):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

to (output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"??>
```

which isn't a valid xml document (and there's also a double `?` at the end of the xml tag).

Am I doing some wrong?

**Edit:** I've got `nokogiri (1.6.0)` installed, which seems to be the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is an open (though very old) Nokogiri issue on [Github](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/388), though it may in fact be a `libxml` issue. I was able to replicate your output.

The quick fix is to parse your document with `Nokogiri::XML` rather than `Nokogiri::HTML`, which is probably better practice anyway when dealing with XHTML files:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open 'wherever')
doc.to_xhtml(:indent_text => "\t", :indent=>1, :encoding => 'UTF-8')
```

Note that this won't preserve your XML processing instruction. If you need it, use `to_xml`.

Comment: Thanks `XML()` with `to_xml()` does seem to preserve the correct xml output.